# Deleting unused component.scss file from angular folder

Tags: css, angular, file, file-structure

I couldn't find a similar question, so I decided to ask about what's your opinion on this.

Let's say I have global style sheet in Angular 2+ project. Angular CLI is generating `component.ts`, `component.scss`, and component.html files.
My question: is deleting `component.scss` a bad practice?
I know that in @Component, `styleUrls` or styles are not mandatory, but wanted to know if this is optimal thing to do.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need `component.scss`, of course you can delete it.

BTW, you can skip creating it when generate the component using angular cli.

```
ng g c yourComponent -is
```